# Is it halal to eat halal food that have enzymes in it

Tags: halal-haram

Basically like the title so the ingredients are whole wheat flour water and unbleached unbromated enriched wheat flour (Niacin (B-Complex vitamin) reduced iron thiamin (b1 vitamin) riboflavin (b2 vitamin) folic acid) contains 2%  or less of each of the following ingredients: calcium propionate a preservative caramel color dextrose enzymes fumaric acid guar gum lactic acid natural flavors salt sesame flour sodium bicarbonate sorbic acid (a preservative ) soybean oil soy flour soy protein concentrate sugar sunflower oil vegetable monoglycerides wheat gluten and yeast and that all ingredients also it Kontos pita whole wheat and have no trans no choleserol and its bioengineered  and have kosher certification and halal and vegan too so is it halal to eat it?